# Compiling a kernel - no bzImage/vmlinuz produced

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, arm, qemu

I'm trying to compile a kernel (altered version of 2.6.32.9, found here https://github.com/rabeeh/linux-2.6.32.9). I am doing the compilation on a emulated ARM system (qemu) (yes, I should probably cross-compile, but that's a different topic) running Ubuntu Core (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core) and the kernel (vmlinuz) from Ubuntu 11.04 (downloaded from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/natty/main/installer-armel/current/images/versatile/netboot/vmlinuz).

After running `make bzImage`, I look in the `arch/arm/boot` folder, and find only a file called zImage. I tried using this zImage instead of the vmlinuz I downloaded from ubuntu.com in qemu, but that doesn't work, just shows a black screen. I guess zImage is not the same as bzImage, which is what I think vmlinuz (judging from different articles on the internet) is.

So, a few questions:

1. Why doesn't `make bzImage` produce a bzImage/vmlinuz?
2. Can I convert a vmlinux to a vmlinuz using for example mkimage (there are lots of guides on the opposite...)?

Thanks

Comment: I've made a fully automated QEMU + Buildroot setup that just works BTW: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the result you describe by asking qemu to emulate a different cpu than arm926ej-s. But booting versatilepb with the default cpu works. I've cross-compiled my kernel, and I compiled all the drivers into it (so I don't use initrd).

Just download 100MB arm-eabi toolchain from http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/ (it's free but they want your email, like the x86 Intel compiler). It has an installer, just say "next" until it's done, like on Windows. Then add the bin directory to your path:

```
export PATH=~/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI/bin/:$PATH
```

Then go back to your kernel source dir and do

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- menuconfig
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- zImage modules
```

You can do

```
sudo make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=path_to_arm_root modules_install
```

if you can reach your ARM filesystem from the host. If you're using NFS root it's trivial, but if you're using a disk image you need to either:

- use a raw disk image and kpartx (depends on your host kernel having dm-multipath) or
- qemu-nbd which supports qcow (and depends on host kernel having network block device support)

To boot in qemu with disk you need the right drivers (SYM53C8XX SCSI). The versatile defconfig doesn't select those.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, especially about the CPU and the SCSI driver! That finally gave me a booting kernel and after adding the SCSI drivers Qemu found my HDD as well! It still doesn't mount it though, even though i have compiled ext2, ext3 and ext4 support, but that's a different issue.

Comment: Does the disk image have an msdos partition table? Does the kernel have MSDOS_PARTITION? versatile defconfig doesn't have it.

Comment: I built in all partition tables into the kernel when I got this error. Every last one of them :) I don't think the disk image is a MSDOS partition though, I created it using dd and mkfs.ext3.

Comment: The Debian installer creates an msdos partition table AFAIK. With a separate swap partition and everything.

Comment: I didn't use the Debian installer, I did this: `dd if=/dev/zero of=rootfs bs=1M count=8096`, `mkfs.ext3 rootfs`, `mkdir mnt`, `sudo mount -o loop rootfs mnt`, `cd mnt`, `sudo tar -xzvf ../ubuntu-core-11.10-core-armel.tar.gz`, `sudo umount mnt`. I guess that does not create a MSDOS partition table, right?

Comment: It doesn't. A kernel seeing a disk drive exposed by `qemu -hda foo.img` really expects a whole hard drive, not a single partition. Do `qemu-img create`, fdisk it, mkfs a single partition from the disk image. Use this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images#Mounting_an_image_on_the_host

Answer (score 4):

The `bzImage` filename and make target was originally x86-specific (big zImage). Many of the bootloaders on architectures that are not equal to baremetal-x86 (SPARC, PPC, IA64, etc. and also Xen on *) directly take `vmlinux` (or one of its compressed forms, for example `vmlinux.gz`, aka zImage). I guess some maintainers just added bzImage as a make target name because they wanted to have the x86 madness on their arch as well.

Comment: Thanks, that explains that part. Do you have any idea what I need to do to be able to run the kernel in qemu (virtual machine)? I'm not sure if vmlinuz is always a bzImage, or if it can be a zImage as well. Perhaps there something else wrong with my zImage, another step I need to do to be able to run it in qemu...